# building bitcoin-qt.exe using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: compiling

I know there is a project libbitcoin-qt.vcxproj, but I have issues with building it. Is there another solution how to build bitcoin-qt.exe (only VS)?

Answer (score 2):

There is documentation about how to build with visual studio 
 on [this link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/build_msvc/README.md). It works fine for me.

Comment: I've built all of the executables except bitcoin-qt.exe following this instruction. Please tell how have you built this exe.

Comment: "Solution and project files to build the Bitcoin Core applications (except Qt dependent ones) with Visual Studio 2017 can be found in the build_msvc directory."  Does it mean that I can't build bitcoin-qt.exe with VS? If yes, then why do we need libbitcoin-qt.vcxproj file in build_msvc?

Answer (score -1):

Independently of how you go about doing this, building with VS is not a recommended or supported configuration (beyond testing reasons).  If you run a system built that way you lose the advantage of the enormous amount of testing put in by users and developers on the supported builds.

At a minimum you should make sure that all the functional tests pass on your build, though this is generally good advice for any build.